# Composer local repository : I can't push because local repository is on my computer

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php, symfony4

I have two repertories in my computer : `VersionableBundle` and `VersionableDemo`.

`VersionableBundle` is part (Symfony 4 Bundle) of `VersionableDemo`. I use Composer Repository for load `VersionableBundle` :

`composer.json` :

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "/var/www/symfony/VersionableBundle"
    }
],
"require": {
    "myname/versionable-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

Three problems :

- I can't push on packagist (because local repository is on my computer) ;
- I can't push and pull (via .git on GitHub) on my second computer (because local repository are not same (Ubuntu / Windows)) ;
- I must push / pull after each `VersionableBundle` change.: **I have a lot of changes to make.**

Is there a better solution ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push to GitHub if you change your repositories *and* configure your composer.json files accordingly.

VersionableBundle's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "your-github-account/versionable-bundle",
    ...
}
```

VersionableDemo's composer.json:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        "your-github-account/versionable-bundle": "dev-master"
    }
    ...
}
```

This should be enough as long as your VersionableBundle is at github.com/your-account/versionable-bundle.

You can get more info on https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md

Comment: Thanks :)But it's very long when you have a lot of change in dev (push / composer update / push / composer update / push / composer update / ...) :/

Comment: Even with a lot of changes, you are already doing a lot of `composer update`, aren't you?

Comment: Another solution: local packages.
https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/02/07/how-to-decouple-monolith-like-a-boss-with-composer-local-packages/